# Yii framework, link doesnt redirect to server

Tags: yii

I have some problem in Yii Link. My application works fine in localhost but i have move it into server. All the link in server is redirecting to localhost. Can anybody help me out in this situation? Should I have to add something more in configuration file. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How can anybody help without relevant code and more specific information?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `CHtml::link()` to create your link? And if you've done it so for the url did you provide an array as follow:

```
array('Controller/Action', 'param'=>value)
```

Example:

```
array('post/list', 'page'=>3)
```

At the end you'll obtain:

```
CHtml::link("your text link", array('post/list', 'page'=>3));
```

(I'm asking it because if you've written every link in hard, it's normal to have each link redirecting to localhost!)